# SQL schema and value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement I want to make.  I want to select

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS FieldName FROM   
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
```

However I want to create another column named Value which is a particular row in table1
so I have rows of the column name and the corresponding single value.  Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: What do you mean "a particular row" in table1? You can add a constant to a SQL query, just `SELECT 'Value'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query produces a value (the minimum) for each column:

```
    SELECT '''select '+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS FieldName, (select cast(MIN('+COLUMN_NAME+') as varchar(8000)) from '+const.tablename+')'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c cross join
         (select 'AllCurveNames' as tablename) const
    WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = const.tablename
```

However, this produces a separate query for each row.  To combine them together, you need a string aggregate concatenation.  This is how you would do it in SQL Server:

```
    declare @sql varchar(max);

    SELECT @sql = (select 'select '''+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS FieldName, (select cast(MIN('+COLUMN_NAME+') as varchar(8000)) from '+const.tablename + ') union all '
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c cross join
                        (select WHATEVER as tablename) const
                   WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = const.tablename
                   for xml path('')
                  );
    select @sql = LEFT(@sql, len(@sql) - 9);
    exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross join, which is implicit if you just select from two tables with no join (i.e., `from t1, t2`):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS FieldName,
       Table1.MyField
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, Table1
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
AND
    MyTable.ID = 123
```

Comment: See https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with a bit of a crazy solution but it works:

```
declare @tbl_name as varchar(255)
declare @field as varchar(255)
declare @val as varchar(255)
declare @SQL as nvarchar(4000)

create table #tbl ( [FieldName][varchar](255), [FieldVal][varchar](255))

set @tbl_name = 'table1'

DECLARE mah_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM  
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tbl_name

OPEN mah_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM mah_cursor INTO @field 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN



set @SQL = 'set @val = (Select top 1 ' + @field + ' from ' + @tbl_name + ')' 
print @SQL


exec sp_executesql @query = @SQL, @params = N'@val varchar(255) OUTPUT', @val = @val      OUTPUT

 insert into #tbl ([FieldName],[FieldVal] ) values (@field, @val)

 FETCH NEXT FROM mah_cursor INTO @field
 END

CLOSE mah_cursor 
DEALLOCATE mah_cursor 

select * from #tbl

drop table #tbl
```

It loops through each value and adds it.  The Fast_Forward feature optimizes the query for high performance